# Define a relation $R$ on the set $\mathbb{Q}$ by $aRb$ if and only if $|a - b| \leq 1$. Is $R$ reflexive, symmetric, and/or transitive?

Tags: proof-explanation, relations

My process so far.

We know that $aRa$ means that $|a - a| \leq 1$. Which is true, thus, $R$ is reflexive.

Now onto symmetric. $aRb \implies bRa$. This means we have $|a - b|\leq 1$. Now observe:
$$|a - b| \leq 1$$
$$-1 \leq a - b \leq 1$$
$$1 \geq b - a \geq 1\quad\quad \text{times }(-1)$$
Thus, $R$ is symmetric.

Now we need to show whether or not $R$ is transitive. This is where I am not really sure where to proceed.

Any help to point me in the right direction is great! Thanks!

Comment: Consider $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=3$

Comment: Thank you! That seemed a rather trivial answer to a question, that is, it seemed easy. Thanks again @Hyperion.

Comment: No worries-- it always helps to think of concrete examples when youre stuck on a problem

Comment: Begs the underlying issue; apparently there is no way to *algorithmically* attack transitivity for this query.  Therefore, one is **forced** to try examples, and is (perhaps) also **forced** to attempt to **visualize** the issue.  A case could be made that this makes the math problem unfair/inappropriate, balanced only by the simplicity of finding the *counter-examples*.  Most undergraduate math problems will yield to getting down in the mud.  But the mud may depend on the difficulty in finding pertinent examples or counter-examples.

Comment: @user2661923 I not sure I agree.   $|a-b| \le 1$ and $|b-c|\le 1$ implies $|a-b| + |b-c| \le 2$ and $|a-c| = |(a-b) + (b-c)| \le |a-b|+|b-c| \le 2$ implies we can probably have $a$ and $c$ nearly $2$ apart while $b$ is in the middle at less than one apart from each (but more than $\frac 12$ apart from either on average.)... It's *easy* to formalize a *condition* that $a$ and $c$ being true enforces on $b$ and makes the sufficient conditions for a counter example somewhat apparent.

Comment: Interesting rebuttal, which I somewhat agree with, and somewhat disagree with.  Your analysis doesn't refute transitivity, but it does facilitate the *visualization* needed to refute transitivity.  Interesting blend of analysis and *mud*.

Comment: @user2661923 It's technically not true that there is no algorithmic way to attack the problem. One algorithm would be: generate all proofs, one at a time. If the proof proves that the relation is transitive, you're done. If the proof proves that the relation is *not* transitive, you're also done. Of course, this algorithm doesn't always terminate because there are propositions which are neither provable nor disprovable in ZFC (unless ZFC is not consistent), but given that there is an answer, it will get you there.

Comment: @MarkSaving How do you analytically prove that a relation is not transitive **without** finding a counter-example?  In fact, for *any* mathSE queries that have asked that a (inaccurate/invalid) assertion be proven, I don't think I've ever seen a rebuttal other than *counter-example is*.  Not saying that analysis won't theoretically get you there; however, I doubt very much that the OP's class has trained him in *generating all proofs, one at a time*.

Comment: @user2661923 Obviously, you'd never do this in practice. But it is theoretically possible. At the very least, the set of "candidate counterexamples" is countable, so you could iterate through the candidate counterexamples until you found an actual counterexample. The more subtle point here is that almost all mathematics requires more creativity and insight than following an algorithm if you ever want to get anything done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider $|a- b| \le 1$ and $|b-c| \le 1$.

$|a-b| \le 1$

$-1 \le a-b \le 1$ a bit of manipulation to focus on the range of $a$ in terms of $b$

$b-1 \le a \le b+1$

And to do the same for $|b-c| \le 1$

$-1 \le b-c \le 1$

$1 \ge c-b \le -1$

$b-1 \le c \le b+1$

If we have $a$ as low as possible, say $a = b-1$ and $c$ as high as possible, say $c= b+1$ then we have $|a-c| = |(b-1) - (b+1)| = 2$.

So not transitive.

Are you familiar with the triangle inequality?

It states that $|m| + |n | \ge |m+n|$ (try and play and see why this is so...try to guess why it is called the triangle inequality.)

Thus if $|a-b|\le 1$ and $|b-c| \le 2$ then $|a-b| + |b-c| \ge |(a-b)+(b-c)| = |a-c|$. so we have $2 \ge |a-b| +|b-c| \ge |a-c|$.

This *implies* we *might* be able to have $2 \ge |a-c| > 1$ be choosing $a$ and $b$ and $b$ and $c$ far enough apart.